# How to animate first letter with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate `first letter` of a text with pseudo element selector. However it's not working. The code is working fine if I wrape the first letter in span but it's not working with pseudo element selector (`::first-letter`).

```css
div.w-text-h a.w-text-value{display:block;}
div.w-text-h a.w-text-value::first-letter{
    top: 50%; 
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%,-50%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 2px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 3px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 4px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 5px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 6px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 7px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 8px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 9px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 10px 1px #5DADE2,
    1px 18px 6px rgba(16,16,16,0.4),
    1px 22px 10px rgba(16,16,16,0.2),
    1px 25px 35px rgba(16,16,16,0.2),
    1px 30px 60px rgba(16,16,16,0.4);
}



div.w-text-h a.w-text-value::first-letter{animation:animated_div 5s infinite;
   -moz-animation:animated_div 5s infinite;
   -webkit-animation:animated_div 5s infinite;
   border-radius:5px;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;}
   
 @keyframes animated_div
  {
   0%   {}
   20%  {transform: rotateY(20deg);}
   40%  {transform: rotateY(40deg);}
   60%  {transform: rotateY(60deg);}
   80%  {transform: rotateY(80deg);}
   100% {transform: rotateY(100deg);}
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="w-text-h"><a class="w-text-value" href="http://localhost/Developer/">Developer</a></div>
```

If I remove pseudo element `first-letter`, then animation works. I need it on pseudo element `first-letter`

Comment: You can't. You can however make a js class that wraps each letter in a span and target the first span.

Comment: @michaelmano So first-letter can not be used for css animation ?

Comment: Check available rules for this selector first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#Allowable_properties

Comment: @Sraja na I wish. A simple js wrapper works wonders though

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply `transform` to `::first-letter` ([check properties list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#Allowable_properties)). But you can have different wrapper for it, then it's possible. You can use some JS to wrap first letter too.

```css
div.w-text-h a.w-text-value{display:block;}
div.w-text-h a.w-text-value .first-letter{
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%; 
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%,-50%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 2px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 3px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 4px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 5px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 6px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 7px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 8px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 9px 1px #5DADE2,
        1px 10px 1px #5DADE2,
    1px 18px 6px rgba(16,16,16,0.4),
    1px 22px 10px rgba(16,16,16,0.2),
    1px 25px 35px rgba(16,16,16,0.2),
    1px 30px 60px rgba(16,16,16,0.4);
}



div.w-text-h a.w-text-value .first-letter{animation:animated_div 5s infinite;
   -moz-animation:animated_div 5s infinite;
   -webkit-animation:animated_div 5s infinite;
   border-radius:5px;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;}
   
 @keyframes animated_div
  {
   0%   {}
   20%  {transform: rotateY(20deg);}
   40%  {transform: rotateY(40deg);}
   60%  {transform: rotateY(60deg);}
   80%  {transform: rotateY(80deg);}
   100% {transform: rotateY(100deg);}
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="w-text-h"><a class="w-text-value" href="http://localhost/Developer/"><span class="first-letter">D</span>eveloper</a></div>
```